# scrapy empty csv file

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to run my scrapy spider, it returns no error but output his an empty csv file

i'm launching the spider through command line scrapy crawl AnimeReviews -o AnimeReviews.csv -t csv

this is library that i used

```
import scrapy
import json
from functools import reduce
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from AnimeReviews.items import AnimereviewsItem
last_page = 1789
```

this is my spider

```
class AnimeReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'AnimeReviews_spider'
    allowed_urls =['myanimelist.net']
    start_urls = ['https://myanimelist.net/reviews.php?t=anime']

def parse(self, response):
    page_urls = [response.url + "&p=" + str(pageNumber) for pageNumber in range(1, last_page+1)]
    for page_url in page_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(page_url,
            callback = self.parse_reviews_page)

def parse_reviews_page(self, response):
    item = AnimereviewsItem()
    reviews = response.xpath('//*[@class="borderDark pt4 pb8 pl4 pr4 mb8"]').extract()       #each page displays 50 reviews

    for review in reviews:
        anime_title = Selector(text = review).xpath('//div[1]/a[1]/strong/text()').extract()
        anime_url = Selector(text = review).xpath('//a[@class="hoverinfo_trigger"]/@href').extract()
        anime_url = map(lambda x: 'https://myanimelist.net'+ x ,anime_url)
        review_time = Selector(text = review).xpath('//*[@style="float: right;"]/text()').extract()[0]
        reviewer_name = Selector(text = review).xpath('//div[2]/table/tr/td[2]/a/text()').extract()
        rating = Selector(text = review).xpath('//div[2]/table/tr/td[3]/div[2]/text()').extract()
        for i in range(len(rating)):
            rating_temp = rating[i]
            rating[i] = rating_temp.split(" ")[1]
        review_text = Selector(text = review).xpath('//*[@class="spaceit textReadability word-break"]').extract()
        for i in range(len(review_text)):
            text = Selector(text = review_text[i]).xpath('//text()').extract()
        pic_url = Selector(text = review).xpath('//div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/a/img/@data-src').extract()
        item['anime_title'] = anime_title
        item['anime_url'] = anime_url
        item['review_time'] = review_time
        item['reviewer'] = reviewer_name
        item['rating'] = rating
        item['review_text'] = review_text
        item['pic_url'] = pic_url
        yield item
```

this is log after crawling

```
2018-06-22 13:37:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-06-22 13:37:14 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 698849,
 'downloader/request_count': 1791,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1791,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 148209070,
 'downloader/response_count': 1791,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1791,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 22, 11, 37, 14, 546133),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1792,
 'log_count/INFO': 13,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 1791,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1790,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1790,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1790,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1790,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 22, 11, 30, 38, 403920)}
2018-06-22 13:37:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

if you need more informations let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem here are you xpath expressions.
They look like they were automatically generated, and they are too specific.

For example, not even your xpath for `reviews` matches anything.
Something as simple as `//div[@class="borderDark"]` matches all 50 reviews on a page, as does the css expression `.borderDark`.

I would recommend getting familiar with xpath and/or css selectors, and writing your selectors by hand.

Also, you're converting selectors to text (using `.extract`), and then back to selectors (using `Selector`). There's no need to do that, you can simply work with the selectors returned by `.xpath`.